Unity: Script won't delete 1 of the objects if 2 are colliding
I have this C# segment of code to make auto generated rooms, does anyone know why my code won't delete the clones of the object? I've tried a lot of methods, but I can't for the life of me get it to work. The project is in 3D.


{
    [SerializeField] private int intRandomValue;
    public float targetTime = 5.0f;

    public Vector3 SpawnPos;
    //public testscore script;

    void Start()
    {
        SpawnPos = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);


    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        
        intRandomValue = Random.Range(0, 6);
        if (intRandomValue == 1)
            Instantiate(Cube, SpawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
        if (intRandomValue == 1)
            tag = "NewRoom";
        if (intRandomValue == 1)
            SpawnPos += new Vector3(0, 5, 0);
        if (intRandomValue == 1)
            tag = "Room";



        if (intRandomValue == 2)
            Instantiate(Cube, SpawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
        if (intRandomValue == 2)
            tag = "NewRoom";
        if (intRandomValue == 2)
            SpawnPos += new Vector3(0, -5, 0);
        if (intRandomValue == 2)
            tag = "Room";
       
        
        if (intRandomValue == 3)
            Instantiate(Cube, SpawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
        if (intRandomValue == 3)
            tag = "NewRoom";
        if (intRandomValue == 3)
            SpawnPos += new Vector3(5, 0, 0);
        if (intRandomValue == 3)
            tag = "Room";
       
        
        if (intRandomValue == 4)
            Instantiate(Cube, SpawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
        if (intRandomValue == 4)
            tag = "NewRoom";
        if (intRandomValue == 4)
            SpawnPos += new Vector3(-5, 0, 0);
        if (intRandomValue == 4)
            tag = "Room";
       
        
        if (intRandomValue == 5)
            Instantiate(Cube, SpawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
        if (intRandomValue == 5)
            tag = "NewRoom";
        if (intRandomValue == 5)
            SpawnPos += new Vector3(0, 0, 5);
        if (intRandomValue == 5)
            tag = "Room";
       
        
        if (intRandomValue == 6)
            Instantiate(Cube, SpawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
        if (intRandomValue == 6)
            tag = "NewRoom";
        if (intRandomValue == 6)
            SpawnPos += new Vector3(0, 0, -5);
        if (intRandomValue == 6)
            tag = "Room";
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (CompareTag("NewRoom"))
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
    }
}

please help thanks
I don't really know anymore details I can add srry
erm uh filler content here bc word minimum

What GameObject is this script attached to?

Are you saying it deletes one of them but not the other and you want both deleted, or are you saying you want only one deleted but its not doing that? Please answer this with an edit to your question.

A few things:

tag = "Room"; sets the tag of the GameObject that is spawning the child objects, not the child object themselves. To be able to access this new child, we need to keep a reference to it, meaning that we need the if statements to contain more than one line. It should instead be something like:

if (intRandomValue == 1)
{
    GameObject cube = Instantiate(Cube, SpawnPos, Quaternion.identity);
    cube.tag = "NewRoom";
    SpawnPos += new Vector3(0, 5, 0);
    cube.tag = "Room";
}


Now that we've put the logic into a single if statement, you can see how every cube will end up with the tag "Room", since you overwrite it at the end. You should only set the tag one time, with the proper value.

The OnTriggerEnter's CompareTag call checks against the tag of the current (spawner) object, not the object you've collided with. It'll also delete the spawner object, not the room. You'll instead want to check:


void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("NewRoom"))
    {
        Destroy(other.gameObject);
    }
}


OnTriggerEnter will only get called if the spawner object has a (non-trigger) RigidBody and collides with another object that has a trigger collider. I doubt that your room spawner has a RigidBody, what did you actually want to achieve with this OnTriggerEnter callback?


Sorry, the rooms themselves are the spawners, as in they just duplicate themselves.

you need to fix your OnTriggerEnter function:
 void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.CompareTag("NewRoom"))
        {
            Destroy(other.gameObject);
        }
    }

